# Is there a way to activate component editor menu for a concealed component in Delphi

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-5

I implemented two menu items for my component in Delphi IDE with TComponentEditor descendant. They're both supposed to be used with "right-clicking" a component on the form. But can I do this for component that is currently hidden (concealed) by other components? So I select a component with other tools (for example object inspector) and would like to activate one of my context menu items.

Shift-F10 doesn't work (at least in D5).

Bringing the component to top for this task is not an option.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click the component in the Object TreeView (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd>).

- D7: *Menu > View > Object TreeView*
- XE2: *Menu > View > Structure*

Or make a property editor with `paDialog` in the attributes and forward the `Edit` method to your component editor. Then double clicking that property or clicking the ellipsis will bring up the component editor, just like the `Colums` property for `TDBEdit` does.

Comment: Thanks, Object TreeView is probably was introduced later than D5, but seems like special property only for editing can be working solution although a bit like a work around.

Comment: @Maksee: The Delphi IDE is based on OTAPI as any custom property/component editor (or any other extension). I think this is an acceptable solution to your post.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel like writing a something mimicking Delphi IDE's Object TreeView, I suggests you the following resources:

1. [Populating all controls of a container object using recursion](http://delphidev.org/?p=79) (Blog post). Using **TVirtualTreeView** like the Delphi IDE is better than the stock TTreeView to my opinion.
2. Study the commercial [TLMDComponentTree](http://lmd.de/products/vcl/lmdidetools/comp_overview.php)
   of the **[LMD IDE-Tools](http://lmd.de/products/vcl/lmdidetools/)** (Excerpt: This powerful control allows to use a Delphi IDE like **Object TreeView**. Collections, child controls etc. are automatically handled).

[image]